# determinant of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

The question goes like this, 
For a square matrix A of order 12345, if det(A)=1 and AA'=I (A' is the transpose of A) then det(A-I)=0
(I have to prove it if it is correct and provide a counterexample if wrong).

So all that I know is that the given matrix is an orthogonal matrix. I tried to multiply det(A-I) by det(A') and det(A) from the left and right and use the properties of determinants to reduce the expression but that led me nowhere. Is there something that I am missing from the properties of orthogonal matrices or matrices in general? Any hint or reference will really be appreciated. Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\det(A-I) = \det(A - AA^\top) \stackrel{(\ast)}{=}  \det(I-A^\top) = (-1)^n \det(A^\top - I) = (-1)^n \det(A-I),$$where in $(\ast)$ we use that $\det(A) = 1$. This means that if $n$ is odd, then $\det(A-I) = 0$. Now, is $12345$ odd?

Comment: I was able to follow your reasonings but I got stuck on the last equality. How were you able to equate (−1)^ndet(A'-I) and (-1)^ndet(A-I)? Can you explain it more?

Comment: The determinant of any matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $A$ will occur in complex conjugate pairs, other than some 1's and -1's.  You need to show that there is at least one 1, given the order of the matrix is 12345 and the determinant is 1.